# jQuery simple dialog not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog

I'm trying to figure out why my jQuery dialog is not working properly on  this page:

http://bit.ly/nOKwYz

This is the code snippet:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery("#dialog22").dialog();
    });
</script>
```

and I also have:

```
<div id="dialog22">test</div>
```

For some reason it does not load the dialog, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It's gotta be the library order. See this fiddle. Your sample works just fine if you have the library order right:

http://jsfiddle.net/mikethomsen/a25gw/

The way it works is you need to load jQuery.js, jQuery UI's JS and then the jQuery UI CSS, then throw in your custom code.

**Edit**

I replaced my fiddle's libraries with your sample and Firefox says jQuery('#dialog').dialog is not a function. That means you are missing the dialog code from the build of jQuery UI you made. You need to go back to the jQuery UI site and build a new distribution of jQuery UI that includes the other pieces you need.

Comment: But that's what I'm doing.. see here: http://whwp.watcheshead.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/w3tc/min/6f389572.804649.js

Answer (score 0):

To show the dialogo you should first hide it i think:

```
<div id="dialog22" style="display:none;">test</div>
```

and then show it with a button for example

EDIT - look at the fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/LCPJe/

Comment: as far as I know, jquery should automatically hide the dialog and pop it up when the page loads according to the code I have pasted

Answer (score 0):

Where do you load jQuery (and jQuery UI) on that page?  You need to reference those libraries in the page (specifically before any code that uses them).  Unless I'm just not seeing the reference, you do have quite a few script tags in the header.

You don't have to host a copy, though.  You can reference [a CDN link](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery#CDN_Hosted_jQuery).

Comment: I'm loading it at the beginning of the HTML, it's all minified here: http://whwp.watcheshead.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/w3tc/min/6f389572.804649.js